# Get App Roles for user limited to the requesting app

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am using OAuth 2 ROPC flow for the application to authenticate the user, and I want to know what roles were assigned for that user, so the application knows that features to enable/disable.

I've successfully obtained all app roles for a user by hitting the https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/appRoleAssignments REST url with a current access token in the header. However, I really don't care about any roles aside from the roles the user has for the app from which he is making the request. Is there a way to limit it to the app making the request or a particular client_id?

Comment: Any update this issue?

Comment: @JoyWang working on testing the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another reply is not correct, you need to filter with the `Object ID` of the corresponded service principal of the application, not the `Object ID` of the application.

Firstly, use the query below to get the `Object ID` of the corresponded service principal of the application, replace the `<client_id>` of yours.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals?$filter=appId eq '<client_id>'&$select=id
```

[image]

Then use the query to get the `appRoleAssignments`, pass the `id` above to the query.

**Note:** There is no `''` surround the `978xxxx383d52bf`.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/appRoleAssignments?$filter=resourceId eq 978xxxx383d52bf
```

[image]

Comment: Result on the second step is error: { "code": "Request_ResourceNotFound", ....

Comment: @ChristopherPisz Can you make sure the user have the role from the target app? Looks he doesn’t from the error.

Comment: @JoyWang actually but my response is correct, his problem is now authorization :)

Comment: I have an app role with the app that is the client id. I configured it myself and can see it if I make a query for all my roles using https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/appRoleAssignments without the filter

Comment: Got it to work. Had to play with it a bit in Postman

Answer (score 0):

You can with this:

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/appRoleAssignments?$filter=resourceId eq <application object (not app) id>`

To get the application object id:

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications?$filter=appId eq '<application app (client) id>'&$select=id`

Comment: Result on the first step is "error": { "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied", ....

Comment: @ChristopherPisz please share the full error detail and response status code.

Comment: {
    "error": {
        "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
        "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-01-06T15:44:19",
            "request-id": "<an id>",
            "client-request-id": "<another id>"
        }
    }
}

Comment: StatusCode - 403 Forbidden

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the Tokens that you will receive the app Roles in the Token and you don't need to make additional call to the Graph API.